# Electron:The bubbling event on webview

Tags: electron

I am using electron version 5.5.1 on Windows10.

I opened the web page in webview and added the ‘contextmenu event' to the web element. And then I added the `contextmenu` event to the webview.

It works in the webview, but when I right-click to open the context menu, the `webview` event is also triggered. How can I avoid that the `webview` event is also triggered?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is web Example

```
    <html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
   <div oncontextmenu="jjc()" style="width:100px;height:100px;border: 1px solid red;"></div>
    </body>
    <script>
    function jjc(){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("1");
    }
    </script>
</html>
```

this is webview style

```
<webview ref="webview" style="height:93%; width:100%" v-on:contextmenu ="handlex.onContextMenu($event,selectPage,index,false)" plugins />
```